# how do i do this in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, task

I have a previous app written with sinatra that follows a similar behavior as in the code bellow

```
require 'sinatra'

class A
  attr_accessor :tick

  def initialize
    @tick = 0
  end
  def start
    while true
      @tick +=1
      sleep 10
    end
  end
end

t = A.new
Thread.new do t.start end

get '/' do
   t.tick
end
```

It launches a couple of threads at boot, each one a process to its own class and it runs fine, im able to get and set values over the browser and store most data in a mysql backend mostly like a MVC setup yet on Rails Im unable to reproduce the same behavior, although im a complete noob at Rails i haven't found a clear solution to this

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do here? Are you just returning the number of times the loop in class A has run?

Comment: I feel that this question is too generic. Please, provide a real life example: eg. what are you trying to achieve using Threads? What the main objective?

Comment: one of the threads i start in my sinatra app is a bitcoin ticker. It get the current bitcoin price from mtgox, saves it to the database checks if it has to sell or buy bitcoins according to each user setting and current portfolio. A user then uses the web interface to check status and change settings etc.. and as an admin im able through sinatra to start stop and check status of each thread. And thats what im hopping to achieve in Rails
I've tried whenever and daemons-rails gems but it didnt did trick for me and i wanted a more built in solution rather than using external gems, if possible

Comment: tl;dr version, i want to use rails as frontend to the code running bellow (in threads in this case)

Comment: It would be better if the comments were edited into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a background task manager in rails for this kind of functionality. There are a [few alternatives for this](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs).

I have used [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) in the past, it is really easy, uses your current database to store jobs and results (no extra dependencies).

But in your case I would propose to use [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque): it uses redis (so that is a dependency, if you can live with that), but it has a built-in admin console to check the running jobs and manage them. Seems like a perfect fit :)

Comment: tks for the reply @nathanvda im liking what im reading about delayed_job :) will i be able to interact with a running task or schedule it to run every x minutes with delayed_job ? tks again

Comment: Sure, the easiest way imho is to reschedule the job at the end of a job  itself. Another alternative is to include a module like this: https://gist.github.com/1024726 which actually does the same but with a cleaner syntax :)